# c# get process with high CPU usage

Tags: c#, cpu

I am looking for a way to get the process name which is consuming the highest CPU. Here is my code which gets the process's CPU usage

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PerformanceCounter myAppCpu = 
        new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", "OUTLOOK", true);

    // will always start at 0
    float firstValue = cpuCounter.NextValue();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    // now matches task manager reading
    int secondValue = (int)cpuCounter.NextValue();
}
```

For whole system CPU, I have

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

// will always start at 0
float firstValue = cpuCounter.NextValue();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
// now matches task manager reading
int secondValue = (int)cpuCounter.NextValue();
```

Is there any way so that I can find most CPU consuming process ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The code gets a list of all runnig processes and assigns a PerformanceCounter to each of them. It then queries the counters with an intervall of 1000ms. Only the values with > 0% are outputted in descending order to the console.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ProcessCount
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var counterList = new List<PerformanceCounter>();

            while (true)
            {
                var procDict = new Dictionary<string, float>();

                Process.GetProcesses().ToList().ForEach(p =>
                {
                    using (p)
                        if (counterList
                            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.InstanceName == p.ProcessName) == null)
                            counterList.Add(
                                new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time",
                                    p.ProcessName, true));
                });

                counterList.ForEach(c =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/
                        // articles/12984.understanding-processor-processor-
                        // time-and-process-processor-time.aspx

                        // This value is calculated over the base line of 
                        // (No of Logical CPUS * 100), So this is going to be a 
                        // calculated over a baseline of more than 100. 
                        var percent = c.NextValue() / Environment.ProcessorCount;
                        if (percent == 0)
                            return;

                        // Uncomment if you want to filter the "Idle" process
                        //if (c.InstanceName.Trim().ToLower() == "idle")
                        //    return;

                        procDict[c.InstanceName] = percent;
                    }
                    catch (InvalidOperationException) { /* some will fail */ }
                });

                Console.Clear();
                procDict.OrderByDescending(d => d.Value).ToList()
                    .ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine("{0:00.00}% - {1}", d.Value, d.Key));

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain what this code does and why it answers the question. Also, why divide by `ProcessorCount`? This doesn't change which process is the heaviest.

Comment: Thanks to your sugestion, I completely rewrote the code.

Comment: Does this list include the system idle process? If it does you should probably filter it out of the list. If not, its a good solution to the question. :)

Comment: It does include the idle process. I'll add it as an option in the code

Comment: The `Process.GetProcesses().ToList().ForEach(p => counterList.Add(new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", p.ProcessName, true)));` should likely be outside of the `while(true)` loop, if not you are going to start getting duplicated items in the list. Also the `if (procDict.ContainsKey(c.InstanceName))` is unessesary, the line `procDict[c.InstanceName] = percent;` can be used for both add and update, you don't need a separate call to `procDict.Add`.

Comment: Thanks @ScottChamberlain, I implemented both of your suggestions.

Comment: Processes should ideally also be `Dispose`d.

Comment: @Rotem Thanks, I added the using statement